# Let $X$ be an irreducible scheme. Are closed subsets of $X$ irreducible?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Suppose $X$ is irreducible, then $X \times \mathbb{A}^1$ is irreducible.

Is $X \subset X \times \mathbb{A}^1$ still irreducible when considered as a closed subscheme of $X \times \mathbb{A}^1$ ?

Comment: Irreducibility doesn't depend on a choice of embedding.

Comment: Furthermore, the title of the question is definitely confusing and not fitting the question.

Comment: Being irreducible is more like being compact than being closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Irreducibility is a property of schemes (or really of topological spaces), not of subschemes of other schemes.  So it doesn't make sense to ask whether $X$ is irreducible "as a closed subscheme of $X\times\mathbb{A}^1$".  It's still the same scheme (up to isomorphism) regardless of whether you think of it as a subscheme of some other scheme, and so it is still irreducible.  It's like asking whether a group remains abelian when you consider it as a subgroup of some other group--the fact that it's a subgroup is totally irrelevant.

Comment: Ok sure. That really clears it up. Thank you!